# GWT application does not realize front end changes

Tags: java, maven, gwt, uibinder

I am trying to update the front end of GWT webapp. I am using maven as my build system and am hosting my app on a tomcat server. My problem is as follows. I change something in a widget (ui.xml file). I recompile with `mvn clean install`. Compilation is successful. I then run my compiled web application on a tomcat server. Everything loads fine, but when I see my web app nothing has changed even though it is different within the code. I am able to see changes in functionality when I change the java code, but when I change something on the front end in a ui.xml file, nothing changes. My compiled webapp is built in the `target/projectName/` folder.

I delete and repopulate the build directory with the `mvn clean` goal. I have also tried clearing the cache in my browser. I also have forced gwt recompilation on every `mvn install` command.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.8.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
    <configuration>
        <force>true</force>
        <compileReport>true</compileReport>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <printJavaCommandOnError>true</printJavaCommandOnError>
        <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>                  
    <superDevMode>false</superDevMode>
    <runTarget>PROJECTNAME.html</runTarget>                                      
    <modules>
        <module>com.projectname.PROJECTNAME</module>
    </modules>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am expecting that the recompiled code contain my changes, and that any potential ways that my code is overwritten by old builds be handled by forced gwt recompilation and the `mvn clean` goal.

EDIT ::

I have been able to make changes to the front end with by using the ui.xml file's owner class (I am referring to the java file associated with the ui.xml file), but I am still unable to realize changes made in the ui.xml file

Comment: where does those .ui.xml files live? in a resource folder or in the src folder?

Comment: the ui.xml files live in the src folder

Comment: probably, your compilation is working fine. Maybe you have a cache problem and your browser is loading your previous version, or you are not adding the just-compiled GWT app to your war. What do you mean with 'run my compiled web app on a tomcat server'? what's the problem with devmode and codeserver?

Comment: @IgnacioBaca There is no problem with devmode anymore, I was fundamentally misunderstanding how that worked. I have tried a hard reset on my browser and that has not changed anything. What I mean about running my compiled web app on a tomcat server is that I have a symlink between the compiled web app folder and tomcat's `/webapp/` folder.

Comment: Then, are you developing using the codeserver and it updates correctly?

Comment: Yes, when I update the interface using java in the owner class, I see the change. Changes in the ui.xml are still ignored. @IgnacioBaca

Comment: Your ui.xml is in src/main/java or src/main/resources? Maven might be copying the ui.xml to the target folder, so after that, if you modify the src ui.xml it ignore it bc it uses the target folder one, so check this out

Comment: @IgnacioBaca my ui.xml is in src/main/java, there is no src/main/resources in my project structure. The only other folder in src/main is /src/main/webapp

Comment: And, find some ui.xml in your target folder, try to confirm if it is copied to the target folder and this copy is blocking gwt compiler to read your actual source file

Comment: @IgnacioBaca Thank you for your help. I actually figured out the problem. The app I'm working on makes use of gwt's localization abilities. So I was trying to add stuff without adding the proper localized value.